Galaxy harassment; flyby encounter (tidal interaction)

This following image is from the paper https://adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1978AJ.....83..219R#page=4
It shows the path of a flyby encounter of NGC 3627 (M66) with the galaxy NGC 3628 (the Hamburger galaxy) from the Leo Triplet group 0.8 Gyrs ago.

The image above is from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.13015.pdf#page=3
the right figure is a peak intensity map of HI-spectra, and we can see that left of NGC 3628 we can see a plume made from HI, where it's marked in red as "the plume". We can also see this plume from the first image.
My question is about the direction of the plume, why it's mostly westward of the galaxy NGC 3628. Let's look at this edit I have made

I think the reason why it's oriented like that is because of the path AB, but when the flyby galaxy took the path CD, why are there no tidal interactions or plumes to be seen south of the galaxy NGC 3628 just like the westward plume?

Please edit your links to point at article abstract pages, rather than at PDFs.
